# Incorrect Range Width (is 1 but should be 2)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep getting an "Incorrect range width is 1 but should be 2" error and I'm not sure why. This exact same bit of code works in the same project on another script on the same sheet without issue.

The Logger outputs '2.0' for `widthApplied2` as expected.

Even if I manually list the "width" (`numColumns`) as "2" it doesn't work. Using the variables `numColumns` and `widthApplied2` doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
var arrayApplied = listApplied.split(',');
var arrayApplied2 = [];
while (arrayApplied.length)
    arrayApplied2.push(arrayApplied.splice(0,2));
var lengthApplied2 = arrayApplied2.length;
var widthApplied2 = arrayApplied2[0].length;
//Logger.log(arrayApplied2);
//Logger.log(lengthApplied2);
Logger.log(widthApplied2);

//PASTE APPLIED TEAMS TO SHEET
var startRow = 15;
var startColumn = 7;
var numRows = lengthApplied2;
var numColumns = widthApplied2;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tyW1n-wBZVygFSovF3Z3NrlqDjsANzOyL7aIayTCdFQ');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('test');
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, lengthApplied2, widthApplied2);//dynamically changes range size based on array size

range.setValues(arrayApplied2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setValues` expects a rectangular 2D array--an array whose elements are themselves arrays of the values to be set, and which have the same length. Your code here doesn't show what `listApplied` is, but the use of `split` implies it is a comma-separated string of values.

Therefore, `arrayApplied` is a `String[]` (an `Array` whose elements are `String`s).
The [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method with 2 arguments returns a new `Array` with the modified contents. which will be another `String[]` with length 2. For example:

```
var a = 'Hello,There,Friend';
var aArr = a.split(','); // ['Hello', 'There', 'Friend']
var b = aArr.splice(0, 2); // b = ['Hello', 'There'] & aArr = ['Friend']
```

If we exhaust `aArr` by splicing into some target array, we will end up with

```
var c = [
  ['Hello', 'There'],
  ['Friend']
];
```

This is indeed a 2D array, but it is not rectangular - one of the elements has length 1, while the rest have length 2.

For this case, the bad element can only be the last one. In general, perhaps there is some other operation that determines the elements of a row (instead of `.splice(0, 2)`), so one can determine the bad element (and pad it if appropriate) with something like this:

```
function fixer_(input) {
  const maxLen = input.reduce(function (curMax, row) { return Math.max(curMax, row.length); }, 0);
  input.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (row.length < maxLen) {
      console.log('Row index ' + index + ' was too short. Padding it with ""');
      row.push('');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That gives me something to work on and look into. Thanks!